# OpenCV Java 4.7.0 image processing ten times slower than 4.6.0 (Windows 10)

Tags: java, windows, performance, opencv

I compiled my Java image processing program identically between OpenCV 4.5.0 and 4.7.0 except for changing to the new OpenCV opencv-470.jar and opencv_java470.dll in the classpath. I went from processing about 3 images per 1 second to 1 image per about 3 seconds.

The results are identical and correct but now very slow.

I don't see any related posts on the Internet about this issue. What have I missed?

A **MRE** with only the `imread` with the OpenCV build information and CPU time as suggested in comments is shown further below.

OpenCV version 4.6.0 operates with the same fast speed as 4.5.0 so that is used for the MRE to compare with 4.7.0.

I can report an OpenCV issue, if it appears that I didn't make a configuration error.

Original Application Processing (not the MRE) is:

```
imread jpg file
convert Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2YUV
resize Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR
blur BlurType.get("Gaussian Blur")
split
normalize Core.NORM_MINMAX
equalize
resize Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR
adaptive threshold Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY

System.currentTimeMillis() [milliseconds] to process 137 images

                4.5.0       4.7.0
                _____       _____
imread          69943      173004
convert          9054      324540
resize           2090       44447
blur                0           0 
split              78         120
normalize          21         648
equalize           25          77
resize             14          22
adaptive threshold 14          64
```

**MRE**
Results [seconds] for 922 jpg files:

> 4.6.0 `imread` elapsed time 425.56, total CPU time  419.765625, user CPU 396.359375
>
> 4.7.0 `imread` elapsed time 1121.974, total CPU time 1116.5625, user CPU 1093.375

```
/*
 * test OpenCV performance
 * compare imread time between 4.6.0 and 4.7.0
 */
package app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

public class App {
  static ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
  static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); // Load the native OpenCV library
    System.out.println("OpenCV version " + Core.getVersionString() + "\n" + Core.getBuildInformation());

    System.out.println("time support " + threadMXBean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported());
  }

  static String imageDirectory; // start search directory (*.jpg files selected)
  static final App x = new App();
  static int countFiles = 0; // number of imreads

  static long imreadTime = 0; // System.currentTimeMillis()
  static long imreadCPU  = 0; // threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime()
  static long imreadUser = 0; // threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadUserTime()

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(args.length > 0) {
      imageDirectory =  args[0];
      System.out.println("Searching JPG files starting in " + imageDirectory);
    }

    Filewalker fw = x.new Filewalker();
    fw.walk(imageDirectory); // SEARCH FOR JPG AND imread THEM

    System.out.println("\nend file walker imread elapsed time "
       + imreadTime*1.e-3 + ", total CPU time " + imreadCPU*1.e-9 + ", user CPU " + imreadUser*1.e-9);
   }

  public class Filewalker {

    /**
     * Called recursively for subdirectories
     * @param path
     */
    public void walk(String path) {

      File root = new File(path);

      // Create a FilenameFilter
      FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file)
        {
          return file.isDirectory() // process all directories and files ending with ".jpg"
              || (file.canRead() && file.getName().length() >= 4
                  && file.getName().substring(file.getName().length() - 4).equalsIgnoreCase(".JPG"));
        }
      };
      // ! Create a FilenameFilter

      File[] list = root.listFiles(filter);

      if (list == null)
        return;

      for (File file : list) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file.getAbsolutePath()); // recursive invocation to subdirectory
        } else {
          // process this file as an OpenCV image Mat
          countFiles++;
          if(countFiles%10 == 0) { // show progress
            System.out.println(countFiles);
          }

          Mat src = null;

          imreadTime -= System.currentTimeMillis();
          imreadCPU  -= threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
          imreadUser -= threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadUserTime();

          src = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString(), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

          imreadTime += System.currentTimeMillis();
          imreadCPU  += threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
          imreadUser += threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadUserTime();

          if(src != null) {
            src.release();
          }
        }
      }
      // the end of the file list for this directory
      // recursive invocations unwind here at the end
    }
  }
}
```

**4.6.0 Build and Run Information:**

```
C:\Users\RKT\frc\FRC2023\Code\OpenCVtest>java -showversion -jar OpenCVtest.jar "C:\\Users\\RKT\\Pictures\\Sony_DSC_Complete_Editing"
java version "12" 2019-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
OpenCV version 4.6.0

General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.6.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-06-05T15:49:50Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.16299 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.20.21032501-MSVC_2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24245.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP3  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP3  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP3   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP3 /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java ml objdetect photo python2 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    python3 world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 ts
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.12)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 C:/utils/soft/python27-x64/python.exe (ver 2.7.13)
    Libraries:                   C:/utils/soft/python27-x64/Libs/python27.lib (ver 2.7.13)
    numpy:                       C:/utils/soft/python27-x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.4)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-2.7

  Python (for build):            C:/utils/soft/python27-x64/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         C:/utils/soft/apache-ant-1.10.12/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.10.12)
    JNI:                         C:/utils/soft/jdk1.8.0_333/include C:/utils/soft/jdk1.8.0_333/include/win32 C:/utils/soft/jdk1.8.0_333/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/build/master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------


time support true
Searching JPG files starting in C:\\Users\\RKT\\Pictures\\Sony_DSC_Complete_Editing

.
.
.

922 files

end file walker imread elapsed time 425.56, total CPU time 419.765625, user CPU 396.359375
```

**4.7.0 Build and Run Information:**

```
C:\Users\RKT\frc\FRC2023\Code\OpenCVtest>java -showversion -jar OpenCVtest.jar "C:\\Users\\RKT\\Pictures\\Sony_DSC_Complete_Editing"
java version "12" 2019-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
OpenCV version 4.7.0-dev

General configuration for OpenCV 4.7.0-dev =====================================
  Version control:               4.7.0-1-g9208dcb07c

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-12-28T16:14:24Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19045 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.23.3
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1928
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (32 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.28.29334.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java ml objdetect photo stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    python3 world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 python2 ts
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.13)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/GHA-OCV-2/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/build-bindings-64/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/GHA-OCV-2/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/build-bindings-64/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/GHA-OCV-2/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Python-3.9/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         C:/apache-ant-1.9.15/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.9.15)
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/GHA-OCV-2/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/install-bindings-x64
-----------------------------------------------------------------


time support true
Searching JPG files starting in C:\\Users\\RKT\\Pictures\\Sony_DSC_Complete_Editing

.
.
.

922 jpg files for imread

end file walker imread elapsed time 1121.974, total CPU time 1116.5625, user CPU 1093.375
```

Comment: please present the result of `cv::getBuildInformation()` for each

Comment: Maybe you should post a bug report to OpenCV, instead of asking a question here on SO.

Comment: system resource usage (CPU) would be interesting to look at.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz TIL `getBuildInformation` , `getCurrentThreadCpuTime`, and `getCurrentThreadUserTime` . Please advise if that is helpful or not to answer the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will post an OpenCV issue if it appears I didn't make a mistake but I thought I might have missed a configuration parameter or was using the wrong OpenCV download.

Answer (score 0):

This issue of OpenCV Java 4.7.0 being slow will be corrected in 4.8.0 which returns to the faster speed of 4.6.0.

[opencv/opencv] OpenCV 4.7.0 much slower than 4.6.0 for Java Apps (Issue #23590)

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems that SIMD to be disabled as getBuildInformation() shows.

**4.7.0 Build and Run Information:**

> ```
> JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
>   SIMD Support Request:      YES
>   SIMD Support:              NO   <<<---
> ```

So the optimization code for JPEG decorde does not work, and then it takes slower.